# put the values in the object and best way for get old value

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Good morning all,

Here I have two small questions I think my code is not optimized and I would like some of your help because I try more solution but it does not work.

I use v-model to modify my object but one can not save the modifications so I will search in axios the object in my DB and then I give him the initial values. my object comes from a parent component for start component, in the parent I make a v-for

```
    <span v-if="number.edit">
        <i class="fas fa-window-close text-danger" @click="onClickClose"></i>
    </span>

    onClickClose(){
        axios.get('number/'+this.number.ref)
            .then(({data: data}) => {
                console.log(data);
                this.number.status = data[0].status;
                this.number.number = data[0].number;
                this.number.route = data[0].route;
                this.number.uri = data[0].uri;
                this.number.refcli = data[0].refcli;
                this.number.refcarrier = data[0].refcarrier;
                this.number.porting_date = data[0].porting_date;
                this.number.portout_date = data[0].portout_date;
                this.number.emergency_active = data[0].emergency_active;
                this.number.emergency_zipcode = data[0].emergency_zipcode;
                this.number.memo = data[0].memo;
                this.number.carrier = data[1];
                this.number.edit = null;
            });
    },
```

Is there any other way than doing this on axios? a place where the basic values are stored even after modification (VueX?) and then do other than each field manually from my object. I would like something like that.

```
axios.get('number/'+this.number.ref)
                .then(({data: data}) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.number ={
                        status : data[0].status,
                        number : data[0].number,
                        route : data[0].route,
                        uri : data[0].uri,
                        refcli : data[0].refcli,
                        refcarrier : data[0].refcarrier,
                        porting_date : data[0].porting_date,
                        portout_date : data[0].portout_date,
                        emergency_active : data[0].emergency_active,
                        emergency_zipcode : data[0].emergency_zipcode,
                        memo : data[0].memo,
                        carrier : data[1],
                        edit : null,
                    }
                });
```

Thank's for your help, excuse me if I express myself badly. Let me know and I'll explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try shortening your code to this (mostly es6):

```
   .then(({ data: {0: firstElData}, {1: secondElData }) => { 
     const { status, number, route, uri, refcli, refcarrier, porting_date, 
      portout_date, emergency_active, emergency_zipcodem memo } = firstElData
      this.number = { status, number, route, uri, refcli, refcarrier, 
      porting_date, portout_date, emergency_active, emergency_zipcodem memo }
      this.number.carrier = secondElData
      this.number.edit = null;
```

Although I am not 100% sure what you are asking.

Of course if all you need is to store original value then put them in a variable when they come in `originalData` and then you can access that later no need for a store for that.

Comment: with vuex or other, we do not know to have a object.old and object.new?

Comment: no, you can have that with a watcher, the watcher:
```someVal(newVal, oldVal){
   //do something
}```